# Is SocketIO Middleware called for each incoming event or just once upon connection?

Tags: socket.io

The docs say the following for `io.use(middleware)`:

> Registers a middleware, which is a function that gets executed for every incoming Socket, and receives as parameters the socket and a function to optionally defer execution to the next registered middleware.

I understand that this means it will be called only once before the connection event is invoked is this right?

Additionally, how would I best implement middleware that is executed for each incoming event?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that

> which is a function that gets executed for every incoming Socket

means that it is executed every time, you can then call next() if you want to pass the "socket" to the next middleware.